# Always opening external links in incognito window Chrome on Mac OS

Tags: macos, google-chrome, private-browsing

Until version 68 Google Chrome when you clicked on external link it would open it window that is currently active no matter if it is incognito or not. Now, when you click on external link and Incognito window is window that you are currently on it would open it in current non-incognito window.

This is not a bug, this is the way Chrome is supposed to work as stated here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/yefXCMUfjz8

Is There a way to edit how external links open on Mac OS Google Chrome? I would like to always open external links in incognito window

**In Windows 10 you can do this by changing Regedit.exe:**

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command

**From**
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -- "%1"

**To** 
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -incognito -- "%1"

Can something similar be done on Mac OS?

Answer (score 0):

defaults write com.google.chrome IncognitoModeAvailability -integer 2

Comment: Welcome to Super User! While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so as well as where and how to make that change.

Comment: Please provide some discussion and / or explanation. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

The link to discussion in Chromium bug tracker: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=757253

There is an ChromeBuddy app that looks like made exactly to address this "issue": https://github.com/AndreyGr/ChromeBuddy?tab=readme-ov-file.